# git reflog not showing branch change

Tags: git, reflog

In another question, a user posted the following reflog:

```
8c48bab HEAD@{16}: checkout: moving from develop to 8c48babb10ec2f8f28f364ce57b5095cb080c133^0
54d8daf HEAD@{17}: commit: changed the how function, it seems I was right, wc counts all lines regardless of readable symbols or not.
13d35ed HEAD@{18}: commit: am working on the how function (should be trivial, but I have a bad feeling)
852fb68 HEAD@{19}: commit: I have added some more commands (thought not fully implemented), but more specifically I have changed the pattern matching
33dfc9f HEAD@{20}: commit (merge): change some output settings, asthetics and such. I am working on getting more command options for list previous lin
a248465 HEAD@{21}: commit (amend): added another sanity check for cli parameters
f0ca508 HEAD@{22}: commit (amend): added another sanity check for cli parameters
9e24e91 HEAD@{23}: commit: added another sanity check for cli parameters
0194cab HEAD@{24}: commit: I am working on getting the console improved, this including better color, and more cammand options
8c48bab HEAD@{25}: checkout: moving from master to testing
```

In `HEAD@{25}`, the user switches to the testing branch.  However, in `HEAD@{16}`, the user moves from develop to a commit without a prior move from testing to develop.

How is it possible to change branches without it being reflected in reflog?  I don't believe this user is particularly sophisticated, so I doubt any esoteric tricks were used.

Comment: @RichardHansen - user says it's git 1.7.10.msysgit.1 locally, the server is using 1.7.10.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the user just checked out a particular commit (using the sha1) and then create the branch.

#### Update

Sorry I misread the question. The user might have renamed the branch `testing` to `develop`.

Comment: I think this is the likely reason.  I'll have to try it with the absolute latest git and see if renames are still silent in the reflog.  If they are, I may look at submitting a patch.  It sure would be less confusing if renames were annotated in the reflog.